# Invaild Syntax Python Inside print 2.7.11

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, syntax

Ok so is inside the print function is an error. And I can't seem to get rid of is here is my code:

```
def chaselect():
    print '''
Now you must choose your race '''

    while player.race == None:
        ace = raw_input('''

1. Human
2. Elf
3. Dwarf
4. Orc
 '''))
        if ace == '1':
            print 'You chose human are you sure?' 
            con = raw_input('''
1. Confirm Race
2. Read Lore
3. Go Back
 '''))
```

This is python 2.7.11 so I do not need to do print('e.g')
Now what happens is a syntax error happens inside the print?
How do I fix this? And why is it coming up with this error?

Comment: Please add error text.

Comment: Where var player.race is defined?

Comment: Each of your raw_inputs has an extra close parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input functions have too many parentheses.

```
def chaselect():
    print '''
    Now you must choose your race '''

    while player.race == None:
        ace = raw_input('''

1. Human
2. Elf
3. Dwarf
4. Orc
''')
        if ace == '1':
            print 'You chose human are you sure?' 
            con = raw_input('''
1. Confirm Race
2. Read Lore
3. Go Back
''')
```

I think you should have to use IDE (like PyCharm, Wing IDE).
These editors will catch your typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def chaselect():
    print 'Now you must choose your race '

    while player.race == None:
        ace = raw_input('1. Human \n2. Elf \n3. Dwarf \n4. Orc\n')
        if ace == '1':
            print 'You chose human are you sure?' 
            con = raw_input('\n1. Confirm Race\n2. Read Lore\n3. Go Back')
```